# Is there a device that can add efficiency to editing documents?

Tags: usb, gaming, keyboards, video-editing

I teach high school English. Lots of papers to grade. Students submit electronically, through an online service; the LMS we use is, shall we say, limited. Grading essays online is extremely cumbersome and slow, with tons of interminable pointing and clicking. (There are NO keyboard shortcuts in the LMS.) I think I can partly ameliorate the process by moving to Google Docs for the grading process, since it has at least some keyboard shortcuts, but I want to look for a hardware element to increase efficiency further. Basically, I want to be able to:

- navigate through a document quickly and precisely.
- highlight text quickly and precisely.
- program the controller to keyboard shortcuts in Google Docs and Chrome.
- key in text for comments quickly and precisely.
- program in canned comments (for the stuff I say over and over again)
- tab over to the virtual gradebook (a separate online service) to enter the student's grade.
- possibly do some other stuff that I'm not thinking of just now.

I've been looking around at game controllers, video editing controllers, etc., for ideas; someone suggested I look into macro keypads. I don't know much about any of these devices, so I'm looking for recommendations. My dream would be to never touch the mouse; I understand that that may not be feasible.

### Other requirements

- I would be willing to pay up to 200USD, but naturally I'd love to do this for less if possible.
- Whatever it is has to connect via USB and be Mac-compatible.

Comment: A software based solution may be possible as well. Do you have admin permissions on this computer?

Comment: @JMY1000 I do. What do you have in mind?

Comment: [Karabiner Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements), along with any generic (or fancy!) USB keyboard; there's some other solutions that I'm trying to recall.

Comment: LMS = [learning management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_management_system)